# See a list of fields and what content types they are attached to

Tags: entities

I am trying to troubleshoot an issue with Panels. In one of the content panes, there are token replacements from a field.

I looked at the context menu for the page, and it was provided by a taxonomy. I'm assuming this is a field on a node, but I don't know which one.

We have a number of content types and taxonomies on the site. Is there a way, perhaps through a module, to see a list of all the fields that are on the site, and which content types they are attached to?

I'd like to avoid looking through the fields of each content type one by one, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to go to Admin > Reports > Field List and see a list of fields in the system and their types and what is using it.